Overriding styles from external props
I have an issue with overriding styles from external components in React. I have a basic component badge which has its own less styles but sometimes I need to apply some styles from an external component (see below).
I have this approach in whole project (lot of components) and I'm trying find solution for this because sometimes it works properly sometimes not. I know that problem with priority of CSS. I know that I can add .badgeItem.badgeItem in external component but as I said it is in whole project and find any solution which solve this issue (maybe a style-loader or something).
badge.tsx
import React from "react";
import styles from "./badge.module.less";
import {cn} from "../../componentUtils";

interface IProps {
    number: number;
    className?: string;
}

export const Badge = (props: IProps) => {
    const {number, className} = props;

    return <div className={cn(styles.badge, className)}>
        {number}
    </div>;
};

badge.module.less
.badge {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
}

page.tsx
import React from "react";
import styles from "./page.module.less";
import {Badge} from "@/app/components/components/badge/badge";

export const Page = () => {
    return <div>
        <Badge number={456} className={styles.badgeItem} />
    </div>
};

page.module.less
.badgeItem {
  background: yellow;
}


What is output in the actual HTML? In other words, what does a Page's Badge show as? <div number=456 class="badge badgeItem">? If so, you can just change page.module.less to use .badge.badgeItem as the selector, but you seem to have a problem with that.

easy fix is use this in page.module.less
.badgeItem.badgeItem {
background: yellow;
}, but this is everywhere in my app. So my ask is can I fix this in webpack loader or something.

Two ways I know you can go about this is

Use inline-style as this will overwrite the className styles

export const Badge = (props: IProps) => {
    const {number, className, ...rest} = props;
    return <div className={cn(styles.badge, className)} {...rest}>
        {number}
    </div>;
};

export const Page = () => {
    return <div>
        <Badge number={456} className={styles.badgeItem} 
          style={{
            background: yellow;
           }}
         />
    </div>
};


Use !important flag in styles.badgeItem

.badgeItem {
  background: yellow !important;
}


exactly, but I want fix this everywhere in my app. So I need  solution which allows me to do that everywhere (bcs I dont want think about it everytime). Webpack loader mby? Now it depends on load styles in page and sometimes it works and sometimes not.

I don't understand what you mean by wanting to fix it everywhere in your app. Can't you update badge.module.less to achieve this?

I can but this issue is everywhere in app. I found the soluition. Bad for erformance but fix it. Set webpack for never do codesplitting for css.

I found the solution.
Set webpack: never do codesplitting for css.
config.optimization.splitChunks.cacheGroups = {
   styles: {
      name: "styles",
      chunks: "all",
      enforce: true
    }
}

Bad for erformance but fix this issue.
And for future never use classname props (never style from external components)
